# blank page in php apache centos 6.5

Tags: php, apache, centos, zend-server-ce

I have a webpage in PHP. When I click on a link, blank page is beeing displayed. No error is there. I already started php errors.

I am using  **CentOS 6.5, Zend Server CE 5.5, PHP 5.3, Mysql**

[image: blank page]

[phpinfo details](http://expirebox.com/download/f79c71d6b1a0b652fc2e9d097c24433a.html)

Error log in /var/log/httpd/access_log shows this error

```
::1 - - [24/Jul/2015:11:20:37 +0530] "GET /AssetTrak/admin/labels.php
HTTP/1.1" 500 - "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: HTTP 500, that means your code or your server has a problem. Maybe you should post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` to the top of the PHP script that is showing a blank page. The blank page is caused by "White Screen of Death" which is when a page errors out but error reporting has been disabled in PHP. re-enabling it by using the above snippet will have PHP output the exact script error to you in your browser.